# Opencart Export/Import tool

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I am using Opencart version 3.0.3.3. I uploaded [Export/Import tool](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&member_token=w9ZXgmlu3Ec5TKIhPPP3xLEjv7K1vM5S&extension_id=17&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=60). While exporting products and categories I am getting an issue saying:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type int

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Version 4.9 of the Export/Import tool which will support newer PHP versions.